# file_put_contents from fopen creates different file than a browser

Tags: php

This is driving me crazy. I can download a file from internet through browser and its working fine. However if I write a script that does this for me using PHP, the file ends up being completely different (as per online diff tools).

```
$link = "https://torcache.net/torrent/9AE1726935FF9C08DF422CCE3C4445FC9484478B.torrent?title=[kat.cr]the.big.bang.theory.s08e24.720p.hdtv.x264.dimension.rartv";

file_put_contents($file_name, fopen( $link, 'r'));
```

First I tried to play around with encoding, but that should not matter as the file is binary, right? Also tried file_get_contents instead of fopen first, the same problem.

My PHP app is running on UTF-8 w/o BOM files. Can someone help? What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I got what you mean. The responses from torcache.net are all compressed with `gzip`. If you download the file from your browser, the file is automatically decoded, but if you do the same with php you get the same file but still encoded. You can use [gzdecode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.gzdecode.php) to decodes it.

```
file_put_contents($file_name, gzdecode(file_get_contents($link)));
```

Comment: This was it. You saved me, thanks!:). I dont think I would figure this out by myself. Quite a tricky one. What had me confused was that the encoded file still has exactly the same length as the decoded one. Any idea how is that? Maybe I dont understand gzip, but I would expect different size.

Answer (score 0):

You have some errors in your code.

First you try to add a string to a variable without parentheses.

```
$link = "https://torcache.net/torrent/9AE1726935FF9C08DF422CCE3C4445FC9484478B.torrent?title=[kat.cr]the.big.bang.theory.s08e24.720p.hdtv.x264.dimension.rartv"
```

The next one you try to download that file over https. Check if your openssl is enabled and if `allow_url_fopen` is set correctly in your `php.ini`

https://secure.php.net/manual/en/features.remote-files.php

Comment: Thanks, but it wasnt really the case. First the link is a typo obviously (the semicolon was missing too...) and then if openssl/allow_url_fopen was not enabled I would expect a clear error message and not just different binary file as I state in the question. But maybe I am wrong.

Answer (score 0):

There are 3 ways to solve your problem:

1. enable openssl for https calls
2. Use curl and set the ssl verifier to 0
3. Replace the https with http to make a normal call.

Option 3 is the easiest one.